# Add Solution to Existing Project File in Team Foundation Build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfsbuild

I’ve created a build project using Team Foundation Build in VS2008.  I created it using just 1 of the many solutions that I need to build.  Now that I got it to build with 1 solution, I want to add more solutions to the project file.  How do I add more solutions?

John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined the build, you had to create an MSBuild Project File; By default they go into a folder $/{Project}/TeamBuildTypes/{BuildName}.  Find the .proj file in the appropriate folder, check it out for edit and find the section of the XML file "<SolutionToBuild Include="...">".  Copy that section and update the "Include" path to whatever your solution is.  Once you check it in, your builds will include the new solution(s).

Comment: is there any way to use the MSBuild Project File Creation Wizard to add solutions?  or is the wizard only available when you are creating the project file for the first time?

Comment: To my knowledge the wizard is only for creation, but I have found editing the XML file to be sufficient so haven't investigated further.  If you want to use the wizard, you could always create a new build and scrap the old as a test-run.